# How do I align a table in the section area with PDFsharp or MigraDoc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdfsharp, migradoc

How do I align a table in the section area?

```
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Table tFirma = section.Footers.Primary.AddTable();
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Column cFirma = tFirma.AddColumn(MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Unit.FromCentimeter(3));//Tamaño de la coluna
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Row rFirma = tFirma.AddRow();
rFirma.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.ParagraphAlignment.Center;
rFirma.Cells[0].AddParagraph("Employee Signature");
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, you don't. Not until you write your own wrapper for drawing classes and aligning and such. But it's been ages since I messed with PDF, so might've changed since then.

Comment: @Bjarke Søgaard: Maybe you didn't use MigraDoc when you messed with PDF ages ago. I think it can be done. But I'm not sure whether horizontal or vertical alignment is needed.

Answer (score 5):

You can set `tFirma.Rows.LeftIndent` to indent the table horizontally.

Comment: MigraDoc is a good Library:) 
Is there any straight way to align right/center?

Comment: @John JB: You have to do some simple maths: take the width of the page body (without page margins), subtract the width of the table and this is the indent for right alignment. Divide by two for center alignment.

Comment: I tried getting table width but it returned zero(I may be using wrong property). I am not setting individual column width explicitly though.
As of now I am using **page width * 0.60** i.e., 60% of the page as left indent. But more accurate calculation is appreciated.

Comment: @John JB: The width of the table is the sum of the column widths. I don't know that the default column width is, I always set it explicitly. I'd recommend setting column width explicitly and summing widths up. That will give you all you need to calculate left indent.

Comment: Thanks for quick replies. I've set column widths in calculated width based on percentage. Now it looks good. I'd like to see these enhancements as part of the library itself in future. Your effort is highly appreciated.

Comment: Is this really the only option? There are so many `Alignment` properties that I refuse to believe you cannot use one of those. I couldn't make any of them work so far, though. My table just stays left aligned.

Comment: @TimPohlmann Your question is a bit unclear. `table.Rows.LeftIndent` is a simple answer for the original question. You can get any alignment that way. But there are other, more complicated ways to achieve the same visual effect. There could be simpler ways to get right alignment or center alignment.

Answer (score 1):

To center a table in the center of a section, do use following line:

```
table.Rows.Alignment = RowAlignment.Center;
```